# Vue 3 emit prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm trying to pass an emit prop in VUE 3, every time I pass it I still get false, and prop fails to toggle.

**Accordion.vue**

```
 <template>
    <div class="flex" @click="toggleInfo()">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
 </template
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        value: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      setup(props, { emit }) {
        const toggleInfo = () => {
          emit('input', !props.value)
        }
        return {
          toggleInfo
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<accordion v-model:value="isOpen">
    ...// just data
</accordion>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import accordion from '../components/Accordion.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    accordion
  },
  setup() {
    const isOpen = ref(false)
    return {
      isOpen
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Every time I click on toggleInfo, I still get :

```
false
```

my emit isn't working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`v-model` wiring has changed in Vue 3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#migration-strategy):

- *component's prop name*

  - Vue 2: `value`
  - Vue 3: `modelValue`
- *component's emitted event name*

  - Vue 2: `input`
  - Vue 3: `update:modelValue`

Since `value` is technically a custom `v-model` prop name, you have to adjust the emitted event name to match:

```js
// emit('input', !props.value) ❌ wrong event name
emit('update:value', !props.value)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-v-model-in-vue-3-2wb14?file=/src/components/Accordion.vue:242-284)

Comment: Thankfully your answer is near the top of a related google search.  Was trying to recall why my emits contained the _update:_ prefix. A concise and helpful answer!